# AngularJS Core Module Dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modularity

Let's say I have an app with a customer module, a product module, and a core module. In my app module, I will import all three modules (customer, product, core). Because of this both the customer and product module will have access to the core module. However, if, for example, my customer module relies specifically on a service in the core module, should i also import the core module in my customer module?

Basically, is it a good idea to add my core module import to all modules that require it AS WELL AS in my app module? Or should i just include the core module at the app level and have the other modules trust that a core module will always be imported at the app level?

Comment: Please provide more context as it is not clear if the question is about Angular or AngularJs. Looks like you are asking about the dependency injection as a topic. Is this the case?

Comment: @aUXcoder the first word in the title is “AngularJS”. I also tagged angularjs. Yes, I am talking about dependency injection in angularJS and wondering if modules should have all their required imports imported in their declaration or do you include something like a core module at the app level and assume its presence in the other modules?

Comment: Looks like your are all clear, good luck.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I don't have much experience posting questions so I'm still learning what to include.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much about

> trust that a core module will always be imported at the app level

but how AngularJS manages modules. When you write somethings like this

```
angular.module('app', ['A','B','C']);
```

Basically you are saying that in order for the module `app` to work you'll need to import the modules `A`, `B` and `C`. Afterwards in the module `B` maybe you have to import some other modules

```
angular.module('B', ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']);
```

As you see in this example `C` is required both from app and from module `B`.

AngularJS implicitly builds a tree for this dependencies in which it will have

- app as the root
- `A`, `B`, `C` in the first level
- `D`, `E`, `F` as leaves in the second level, all children of `B`

C is not present again in the second level since it's already present in the first. Angular will then proceed to load all the modules from the root to the leaves looking at the tree.

So, answering your question: **AngularJS is intelligent enough to avoid loading stuff multiple times just because you declared it twice by mistake. By building that tree duplicates are accounted for.**

What you have to avoid doing is this:

```
angular.module('app', ['A']);
angular.module('A', ['B']);
angular.module('B', ['C']);
angular.module('C', ['A']);
```

As you can see the graph generated is this:

```
app -> A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C -> A -> ....
```

And you have a cycle that angular can never resolve.